# What sort of Math do I need to create software in the Oil and Gas Industry?

Tags: math

I'm interested in working in the Oil and Gas Industry as a Software Engineer. What sort of Math is commonly required to work in this industry? Any first hand experience would be beneficial.

Comment: You should contant someone already working in this industry.

Comment: I think this question is interesting. One can discuss the software methodologies _and_ the mathematical approaches. For a start, I know there are two main branches of math you *must* master: linear/convex programming and PDEs/real analysis. Then, generally software in the oil industry are huge computational black boxes written in a "write and forget about maintenance" fashion. [In France], people do this very very badly (and in Fortran). Anyone with a strong math background *and* programming skills should perform well in the oil industry (which is known for the $$$ they pay)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's an awfully general topic. As to what Math topics might be able to help you, I would throw a strong understanding of linear algebra (you can never go wrong with a good understanding in that field). A strong chemestry and physics background is sure to help as well.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on whether your wrting code for accountants or geologists.

In either case, you are unlikely to be your own domain expert.  Someone with deep understanding in your development area will do the heavy lifting.

It'll be helpful to have enough understanding to be able to listen and interpret well, but it's too much to ask that you become a domain expert, too.

Answer (score 0):

Like all industries it depends on what you're coding for. I used to write drivers for computers that counted gas in pipes. I needed very little maths as the counters had the maths was encoded in hardware. So I would say get a get degreee with a maths element and you should be be fine for the maths aspect, unless you specifically need to understand in detail a particular asspect such in which case you needs to be way way more specific in your question.

My personal recommendation? A physics degree. You'll have all the maths you needs for an awful lot of industries.

Answer (score 0):

It's a big field, it really depends what you're doing.  I've been working in utilities for the last three years or so writing business apps - things like demand forecasting and work management systems - and haven't used any maths at all.  There have always been domain experts providing details including any calculations needed.

On the other hand, much of it's essentially trading similar to that in the financial markets, so if you want to work in that area, I imagine some maths might be useful.

But if you want to get into it, I'd just go for it, don't worry about not having enough maths knowledge - you can always get it later if you find you need it.